# What object does msoLinkedOLEObjects refer to?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, powerpoint

Can somebody help me to understand what are `msoLinkedOLEObjects` objects?

Basically my issue here is that, I wanted to change the link sources path of a PPT file from a excel worksheet through VBA, where I'm able to attach the PPT file path into the worksheet, and simply on a click of a button, it would change all the link sources from the worksheet.

I'm pretty sure the objects type are embedded, so I proceed to run. But the link sources did not update. I tried to debug and realize that `msoLinkedOLEObjects` can't be found. When I change a certain value in the excel worksheet, the value in the PPT file change too, so I start to wonder how is that not embedded?

**Below here are my codes:**

Var "linkPth" - PPT's file path.

```
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
ppt.Visible = True
Set oPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(linkPth)

For Each osld In oPres.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObjects Then
            If oshp.OLEFormat.progID = "Excel.Sheet" Then
                oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" _
                    & ThisWorkbook.Name
                MsgBox .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
           End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

(I had spend a week to search up the websites and forums for results but still there was no hope at all. Sorry to brought it up again if there was an answer to it already.)

Answer (score 0):

A few problems here:

It's msoLinkedOLEObject, not msoLinkedOLEObjects

OLEFormat.ProgID will return something like "Excel.Sheet.12", so it'll never = "Excel.Sheet"
Instead, test to see if it CONTAINS "Excel.Sheet" as below.

Finally, you can set the link to point to anyplace you like, but if the file's not where you say it is, PPT won't throw any errors; it'll just ignore you and leave the link as it originally was.

```
For Each osld In oPres.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        'If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObjects Then
        If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then ' not Objects
            'If oshp.OLEFormat.progID = "Excel.Sheet" Then
            If InStr(oshp.OLEFormat.progID, "Excel.Sheet") > 0 Then
                oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" _
                   & ThisWorkbook.Name
                MsgBox .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I just wrote it here without checking the extra 's', my bad. 

I had tried your codes, and it still doesn't work, it does not enter the loop of "If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then", I mean aren't the charts embedded? when the values are able to update through the excel sheet?

Comment: Embedded charts and Linked charts are two entirely different things.  Perhaps you have embedded charts rather than linked.  You might also test to see if oshp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject  If so, the chart is embedded and will have no linkformat.sourcefullname property.  Also, if you're looking at charts and not worksheets, test to see if .ProgID contains just "Excel", not "Excel.Sheet"

Comment: I have tried your method and monitor the .Type value within the local window, it only returns msoAutoShape, msoChart, msoTextBox, etc. And if this is the case, probably I can't change the link source path programmatically.

Comment: That's correct; the only shape types that will have a LinkSourcePath are shapes that are, in fact, linked:  linked OLE objects (not embedded ones) and linked pictures.

Comment: Haha, alright! Anyway, thanks for the help that you provided. Steve. Appreciate it!

Comment: Does not work.  activesheet.shapes(selection.name).linkformat.sourcefullname no such property for an linked word file.  However, old XL95 DrawingObject (from selection) is a Rectangle which has a Formula property that can be set ... but not read!  I need the latter.  It is a real mess, need sheet.OLEObjects but that fails for closed or broken links.

Comment: >> Does not work. activesheet.shapes(selection.name)  ... there's no activesheet object in PowerPoint, so no, it wouldn't work. I'm not sure why this discussion has Excel tags, but it's about PowerPoint, not Excel.